# remove \n inside a string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL that stored a string, and its value is `Group Sales Manager\nInsurance Service since 1983`.
Now, I want to change this part of string into point form, by splitting them using `explode()`, so [0] would be Group Sales Manager, and [1] would be Insurance Service since 1983.
So far, I have tried;

```
<?php 
$description = $row['description']; //the value here is the Group Sales Manager... 1983.
$points = explode("\n", $description);
?> <ul> <?php
for ($x = 0; $x < count($points); $x++) {
    echo "<li>$points[$x]</li>";    
}
 ?> </ul>
```

The thing is, the code works if I manually put that same string inside the `$description` by entering it, but it doesn't work when the value is pulled from a MySQL, I wonder why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By fetching the data from a database, the data will probably be sanitized. That means in this case that `\n` becomes `\\n`.

If that is the case, this is the solution:

```
<?php 
$description = $row['description']; //the value here is the Group Sales Manager... 1983.
$points = explode("\\n", $description);
?> <ul> <?php
for ($x = 0; $x < count($points); $x++) {
    echo "<li>$points[$x]</li>";    
}
 ?> </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?php 
$description = html_entity_decode($row['description']); //the value here is the Group Sales Manager... 1983.
$points = explode(PHP_EOL, $description);
?> <ul> <?php
for ($x = 0; $x < count($points); $x++) {
    echo "<li>$points[$x]</li>";    
}
 ?> </ul>
```

Comment: did you try with `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: Yes, I did. Still no go.

Answer (score 0):

try replace `'\n'` with `'\r'`.

I never test it with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?php 
$description = $row['description'];
$points = explode("<br />", nl2br($description));
?> <ul> <?php
for ($x = 0; $x < count($points); $x++) {
    echo "<li>$points[$x]</li>";    
}
 ?> </ul>
```

The [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function converts whatever new line char to `<br />`